# How to add a class to the link of the default Gutenberg Button block?

Tags: block-editor

```js
function addBlockClass( props, blockName ) {
    if(blockName.name === 'core/button')
    {
        Object.assign( props.children.props, { className: props.children.props.className + ' click-track' } );
    }
    
    return props;
}

wp.hooks.addFilter(
    'blocks.getSaveContent.extraProps',
    'button-add-class/add-block-class',
    addBlockClass
);
```

I have this code and it was working until the update of Wordpress to 5.6.1

Now it is triggering an error:

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined`

Why?

What is the correct way to add a CSS class to the default Gutenberg button `<a>` tag?

I would expect the HTML output to be like this:

```html
<div class="wp-block-buttons">
  <div class="wp-block-button">
    <a class="wp-block-button__link click-track" href="https://example.com/">View Offer</a>
  </div>
</div>
```